# Exclude all transitive dependencies with Apache Maven Shade Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, dependency-management, maven-shade-plugin, transitive-dependency

I have used [Apache Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) to create fat jar (the jar which includes all classes from all dependencies). My current project folder structure looks something like this,

```
> Parent Module (packaging pom)

    > Module 1 (packaging jar)
        > Own classes
        > Dependency-1
        > Dependency-2

    > Module 2 (packaging jar)
        > Own classes
        > Module 1 (I want here only classes written in module-1, not any transitive dependencies)
        > Dependency-1
        > Dependency-2
        > Dependency-3
```

The `pom.xml` snap-shot from Parent Module,

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>common-shade</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

The `pom.xml` snap-shot from Module-1 & Module-2 looks like this,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>common-shade</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The dependency declared for Module-1 in Module-2 pom looks like this,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.com.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>*</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

NOTE : Currently, if I see my dependencies using `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`, then it's showing as expected, but `shade-plugin` is not excluding it.

**Problem** : The module-1 & module-2 have some same dependencies with different versions. If I skip/disable shade-plugin declared in Module-1, then I can run Module-2 with no issues, but if I don't disable it, then the fat jar created by Module-2 includes some **classes from jars with Module-1 versions**, so my Module-2 stops running.

**UPDATE :** 
I use fat jar to run individual modules like this,
`java -cp module.jar com.mycom.Main`

Any help please?

Comment: Which version of the maven shade plugin are you using?